# Merge Data From multiple tabs to one master tab

Tags: vba, excel

I try to merge the data from multiple tabs to one master tab. Since the concepts in those tabs constantly updated every day (always adding the new information), I want to make sure my master tab is always up to date, and include all updated concepts.

Below is the coding I came up with in VBA. However, I could not run it in Excel since the coding  **`erow = DestSh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1UP).Offset(1, 0).Row`**   was always showed a debug issue.

How can I fix this?

```
Sub MergeDataFromWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestShe As Worksheet
    Dim erow As Long, lrowsh As Long, Startrow As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Startrow = 2
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "MyMergeSheet"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MyMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "MyMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "MyMergeSheet"
    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If shtName <> DestSh.Name Then
            'Find the next blank or empty row on the DestSh
            erow = DestSh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1UP).Offset(1, 0).Row
            'Find the last row with data in the Sheet
             lrowsh = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(Startrow), sh.Rows(lrowsh))

            'copies values/formats
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(erow, 1)
                .PasteSpecial x1PasteValues
                .PasteSepcial x1PasteFormates
                Application.CutCopyMode = faluse

            End With

        End If
    Next

    DestSh.Cells(1, 1) = "Current Period Update"
    DestSh.Cells(1, 2) = "Deficiency Reference #"
    DestSh.Cells(1, 3) = "Audit Report Number"
    DestSh.Cells(1, 4) = "IA Reference #"
    DestSh.Cells(1, 5) = "Identifier"
    DestSh.Cells(1, 6) = "Control Matrix Ref. #"
    DestSh.Cells(1, 7) = "Category"
    DestSh.Cells(1, 8) = "Region"
    DestSh.Cells(1, 9) = "Location"
    DestSh.Cells(1, 10) = "Control Activity"
    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreeUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is that a typo here on SO, or also in the code? It looks like you have `.End(x1Up)` (note the number 1).  Try `erow = DestSh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`

Comment: @BruceWayne you're a erow! (sorry - I'm a dad, I'm allowed)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - ...how can we move to dock a user's reputation? Just curious....totally unrelated to Excellent puns.  ;)

Comment: @BruceWayne to be honest, I primarily aimed to highlight the poor & inconsistent naming in this code... but then, couldn't resist that one... sorry again!

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Better a e-row than an e-ror!

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of questions come up all the time.  As always, try something like this.....

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

---

I use the first worksheet of each workbook in my example (index 1). Change the worksheet index or fill in a sheet name: mybook.Worksheets("YourSheetName"). And change the range A1:C1 to your range

```
With mybook.Worksheets(1)
    Set SourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
End With
```

If you want to copy all cells from the worksheet or from A2 till the last cell on the worksheet.Then replace the code above with this

```
With mybook.Worksheets(1)
    FirstCell = "A2"
    Set SourceRange = .Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells))
    'Test if the row of the last cell >= then the row of the FirstCell
    If RDB_Last(1, .Cells) < .Range(FirstCell).Row Then
         Set SourceRange = Nothing
    End If
End With
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm